# How many theologians were censured under popes John Paul II, Benedict XVI, and Francis?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, pope-francis, john-paul-ii, benedict-xvi

This question contains three parts:

1. How many theologians were censured under Pope John Paul II? (1978-2005)
2. How many theologians were censured under Pope Benedict XVI? (2005-2013)
3. How many theologians were censured under Pope Francis? (2013-Present)

Answerers may interpret "censured" as they see fit (e.g. given warnings, forced to retract positions, had teaching faculties revoked, etc.).  The more information, the better.

Comment: See [Latin American liberation theology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_American_liberation_theology), [Hans Kung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Kung), [Catholics for Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholics_for_Choice), etc.